# kineticjs move image on button click

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, move, kineticjs

I am using [this example](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/) to create a canvas etc. What I would like to do is move the position of the `yodaGroup` or `yodaImage` via button click.  Has anyone ever done this or know how to do this?

Here is where I am at.

```
    var yodaGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
      x: 250,
      y: 30,
      draggable: true
    });
```

I want to adjust or add to the x and y cordinates for the yodaGroup above
using a button click that triggers this function below

// need to figure out this function
this is just an example as I don't know how to define for the yodaGroup above as it doesn't have an id or class tied to it.

```
   function left() {
      yodaGroup.x += 5; // move image by 5px
   }
```

Comment: I've done a bit of a project using kineticJS, let me know if you want some help. My project is at http://physiks.netii.net

Comment: Yes would love help... Im just trying to get a html5 canvas using images, and be able to move and resize them with button clicks. Just resizing would be great. I found a different example where they are using buttons to zoom which is what I need but I can't get it to work with an image either... thats here. http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-scaling-a-drawing-with-plus-and-minus-buttons/

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way than set position. Its the .move() function.

.move(x,y) moves on object by given amounts x and y.

so this could be:

```
function left() {
   yodaGroup.move(-5,0);
}
function right() {
   yodaGroup.move(5,0);
}
function up() {
   yodaGroup.move(0,-5); //negative is up in canvas
}
function down() {
   yodaGroup.move(0,5); //positive is down in canvas
}
```

This is also much faster execution than calling getPosition twice and set position after.
Also, setPosition requires more resources and processing than move.

http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Node.php#move

Comment: If you want to move the image/group to a certain position, then you could use .setPosition(x,y)

Comment: I will try these later today when I get home. Been out of town for a couple days. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Tried these suggestion still can't get it to move... always undefined either yodaImg or yodaGroup is undefined. Any other suggestions anyone know how to get canvas drawings into a div id or class... if I could do that I could just use a canvas and use css click functions to move the image. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this should work.  Except don't forget to redraw the layer with layer.draw()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that "x" property is public. According to the API, you should use setPosition() method : http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Node.php#setPosition

I would try something like :

```
<button data-direction="right" value="&gt;">
<button data-direction="left" value="&lt;">
```

Javascript (with jQuery) :

```
var yodaGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
  x: 250,
  y: 30,
  draggable: true
});

var step = 5;

$('button [data-direction=right]').click(function() {
  yodaGroup.setPosition(yodaGroup.getPosition().x + step, yodaGroup.getPosition().y);
});

$('button [data-direction=left]').click(function() {
  yodaGroup.setPosition(yodaGroup.getPosition().x - step, yodaGroup.getPosition().y);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't seem to do anything I get $ is not defined in chrome console.

Comment: you need jQuery http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js or just use vanilla js : document.querySelector(...).addEventListener('click', function() { ... });

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using this... and got it working

html

```
<div class="positionImage">
<input type="button" value="left" id="left" >
<input type="button" value="right" id="right" >
<input type="button" value="up" id="up" >
<input type="button" value="down" id="down" >
</div>
```

script

```
// zoom by scrollong
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("mousewheel", function(e) {
   var zoomAmount = e.wheelDeltaY*0.0001;
   yodaGroup.setScale(yodaGroup.getScale().x+zoomAmount)
   layer.draw();
   e.preventDefault();
}, false)

// move down
document.getElementById("down").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
yodaGroup.move(0,5);
layer.draw();
e.preventDefault();
}, false)

// move right
document.getElementById("right").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
yodaGroup.move(5,0);
layer.draw();
e.preventDefault();
}, false)

// move up
document.getElementById("up").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
yodaGroup.move(0,-5);
layer.draw();
e.preventDefault();
}, false)

// move left
document.getElementById("left").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
yodaGroup.move(-5,0);
layer.draw();
e.preventDefault();
}, false)
```